# How to use multiple Blocs for different UIs?

Tags: flutter, widget, builder, bloc, state-management

I have a Landing UI that doesn't have any Blocs, a Register UI with it's Bloc, a Verification UI with it's Bloc, and a Home UI with it's Bloc.
In each one I defined the BlocProvider.of.
In the main I defined at the Home of Material App a Multiple Bloc Provider with each has it's child and the main child of the provider is the landing Page like this :

```
 home: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
           BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
             create: (context) => UserBloc(UsRepoImp()),
              child: RegisterUi(),
           ),
           BlocProvider<VerificationBloc>(
             create: (context) => VerificationBloc(VerRepoImp()),
               child: VerificationUi(),
         ),
           BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
             create: (context) => HomeBloc(HomeRepoImp()),
               child: HomeUi(),
         ),
        ],
        child: LandingUi(),
      ),
```

**and one more thing the Verification UI is returned from a Register Bloc state like so :**

```
 BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is UserLoading) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator(
                          valueColor:
                              AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Color(0xff7b68ee)),
                        );
                      } else if (state is UserRegistered) {
                        return VerifyAccount();
                      } else if (state is UserError) {
                        return Text('Error');
                      }
                      return SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

***But when I run I have an error that the Bloc shouldn't have an ancestor.***
**How am I supposed to make these Blocs to communicate with UI changings correctly?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `MultiBlocProvider` in a wrong way. you should not provide `child` there, instead only provide the argument of the `create` function there, and then in your widget tree below this `MultiBlocProvider` you can use `BlocBuilder` to listen to any of the provided blocs above in the tree, and if you need to listen to multiple blocs in the same widget, you need to nest `BlocBuilder`s.

example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<RecorderBloc>(
            create: (context) => myFirstBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<PermissionBloc>(
            create: (context) => mySecondBloc(),
          )
        ],
        child:myChild()
      );
```

Then inside **my_child.dart** :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MyFirstBloc, MyFirstBlocState>(
      builder: (context, myFirstBlocState) =>
          BlocBuilder<MySecondBloc, MySecondBlocState>(
        builder: (context, secondBlocState) {
          //return widget based on the states of both blocs...
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```